# How to restart Windows Phone 8 device?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I noticed an app in Windows Phone Store, it can restart WP device, How does the app do it?

http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/%E4%B8%80%E9%94%AE%E9%87%8D%E5%90%AF/75ed45c3-8268-4ca7-b405-17a31ded3810

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do it using public API in the SDK. Maybe there is some "not so public" API  ... or the app just crashes so horribly that the phone restarts.

Anyway, you should not want to do this and such app should never have passed certification.

Comment: I'm just curious how is it achieved.